# Bash script to automate Git pull

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I want to automatically pull from Git. For some reasons it is not possible to automate the password thing in the server I am using. So it needs to be done by a Bash file. Now my Bash coding is not that good. Then it is possible to enter the passphrase for the SSH key. But I have really no clue what to do...

`#!/bin/bash
cd . public_html/auto_deploy/foldername && git fetch --all && git checkout --force "origin/master"`

The above is not working... And then it needs to enter the passphrase, and I have no idea what to do then... How can I do this?

Comment: Define "not working", could you print to stdout to see what bit is failing?

Comment: It is prompting nothing, I would expect something to enter my password, so the bash script can enter the passphrase

Comment: If you're going to embed your password into a script, why not simply ask git to persist the credentials and enter them once? Google for `git credential.helper`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fortunately and according to the core [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), you can use the following command to save your credentials for later on use - instead of typing it each time when prompted.

```
git config credential.helper store
```

> Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk,
> protected only by filesystem permissions. This command stores credentials indefinitely on disk for use by future Git programs.
>
> You probably don’t want to invoke this command directly; it is meant
> to be used as a credential helper by other parts of git

Interesting to check: [Git Credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

Comment: With this solution it is solved, I got managed to get it working with the above code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do Git pull from a shell script, you need to use it like this:

```
git pull https://username:password@git_hostname.com/my/repository
```

Comment: This is only for open repositories, this repository is private and needs to be pulled by the git@ url ssh

Comment: And I still need to change the directory first.

Comment: do you thing this work with personal access tokens??

Answer (score 3):

You can also generate ssh keys using `ssh-keygen` and use the `ssh://` method to `git pull`.

SSH key allows you to establish a secure connection.

Before generating an SSH key, check if your system already has one by running `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. If you see a long string starting with `ssh-rsa` or `ssh-dsa`, you can skip the `ssh-keygen` step.

To generate a new SSH key just open your terminal and use code below. The `ssh-keygen` command prompts you for a location and filename to store the key pair and for a password. When prompted for the location and filename you can press enter to use the default. It is a best practice to use a password for an SSH key but it is not required and you can skip creating a password by pressing enter. Note that the password you choose here can't be altered or retrieved.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$your_email"
```

Use the code below to show your public key.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy-paste the key to your user profile. Please copy the complete key starting with `ssh-` and ending with your username and host.