# Is it possible to directly enter password in bash for a git repo?

Tags: bash, automation, passwords

When i create a repo (like once or twice a week), i have to enter a password 3 times in a row and its kind of annnoying. I already have a script that create a repo, setacl and getacl with blih. It would be nice if i only have to enter it once or not to have to enter it
Thank you ^^
(sry bad english)

Comment: What you are looking for is this, so you will NOT be prompted by passwords anymore : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170553/7723882

Answer (score 1):

Following same on Windows, Mac, and Linux: Open terminal or (bash) type:

> ```
> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your github email.gmail.com"
> ```

Press enter. You will see Enter file in which to save key. Let it save in default folder, press enter. Type password which won't show on screen, press enter. Type password again, won't show, press enter. Then you see key fingerprint and a box art-work looks like jiberish. Type:

> ```
> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> ```

Press enter. Type in password. Go back to github. Go to your profile drop-down menu, click on settings. On left side screen click on SSH and GPG keys button. Click on New SSH key. Give Title (good idea to name of your pc). Go back to terminal (bash) This portion slightly different depending on pc. If on Mac type:

> ```
> pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> ```

press enter, won't show anything (but is copied to clipboard). If on Windows type:

> ```
> clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> ```

press enter, won't show anything (but is copied to clipboard). If on Linux need to use xclip to copy key. Now go back to github paste into Key text field. Click on Add SSH key button. Now github is linked to your pc. (Warning! If you ever sale this pc delete SSH key). Go back to terminal (Bash). cd to Open or make test file. Git add "testing". Git push origin master, press enter. You will get one message 1st time you do this, but once confirmed this never have to do again. (Are you sure you want..) type yes, press enter. It will give Warning: Permanently added..(don't worry, everything correct). Now make one more git push and will go through with no password!